# CORS is enabled but toDataURL still throws a warning

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain, cors, todataurl

As the title says, I've enabled CORS for all of the images, but I'm still getting errors when trying to throw them onto a canvas and then extract that canvas (Chrome and FF).  I ran a little sniffer on one of the images to test it out, and it seems to be in fact returning the correct headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Am I missing something?

Comment: ...and you're also specifying the crossOrigin="anonymous" attribute on the image objects?  If so, that's not the problem and we need a bit more code.

Comment: That solved the problem, @markE.  Thank you.  I'm also trying to colorize these images using PaintbrushJS, but now it's giving me "Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy."  Any idea?

EDIT: It seems like it might be because all my images are being loaded dynamically through JS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *request* CORS usage for the server, just add this attribute to the image tag:

```
<img crossOrigin="anonymous" ... />
```

or dynamically from JavaScript, use it as property (assuming `img` is created or obtained already):

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = callback;
img.crossOrigin = '';   /// = anonymous
img.src = '...';
```

If you have multiple images to load you can use an image loader that supports cross-origin request (for example my [YAIL loader](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/YAIL-imageLoader-for-JavaScript) where you can request all or individual images to be loaded using CORS).